# Cordova Apache wrong module path

Tags: node.js, cordova, command-line-interface, apache-cordova

### My question

I am learning to make a hybrid application with cordova apache (previously Phonegap?) I am following the steps they recommend our their website:

```
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html
```

I successfully installed nodeJS (if I do the command node --version, it will return its version)

But when I try to install cordova, everything seems working, but not the CLI.

So: I guess the CLI is configured incorrect, but I am not sure. Anyone can help me here?

---

### Notes:

- Command used to install cordova (globally):

  ```
  npm install -g cordova
  ```
- Command used to check if it was installed correctly and accessible from the command line (with given errors):

  ```
  cordova --version
  module.js:340
      throw err;
      ^

  Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
      at startup (node.js:138:18)
      at node.js:974:3
  ```
- I found out the path in the error doesn't exist:

  ```
  c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
  ```
- The correct path have to be:

  ```
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
  ```
- I configured this path in my global system environments:

  ```
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm
  ```
- I noticed this file (which needs to be called from CLI I guess)

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  basedir=`dirname "$0"`

  case `uname` in
      *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
  esac

  if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
    "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova" "$@"
    ret=$?
  else 
    node  "$basedir/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova" "$@"
    ret=$?
  fi
  exit $ret
  ```
- I am working on Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue recently. Solved it by doing the following:

`npm -g install npm`

`npm install -g cordova`

The issue was that the version of npm that is bundled with the latest stable version of node does not support some packages.

Answer (score 0):

In windows inside the root folder of the project I found two files cordova.cmd an cordova. Delete those two files