# Cordova add platform error, with android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

When I try tu run `cordova platform add android`, whether it's from a Ionic or Cordova Project, I get the following error:

```
/c/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/npm/cordova: line 14:  1200 Illegal instruction     node "$basedir/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova" "$@"
```

This is my setup:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Gulp version: CLI version 1.2.1
Gulp local:
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.15
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.2
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v4.4.0
```

These are my environment variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
Path: ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I've tried reinstalling cordova, ionic, npm and different versions of Node, but the error remains. Any ideas?

Comment: I think ur android home is ` C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926761/cordova-apache-wrong-module-path

Comment: Have u tried mapping to sdk\tools ???

Comment: @Learner, I've changed ANDROID_HOME variable to the one you specified, but with no success.

Comment: @AlexandruPufan ANDROID_HOME should point to android sdk folder not sdk\tools

Answer (score 0):

> I believe your nodejs installation folder is not set in your `Path` system environment variable. Please ensure to add the same.

Once its done, try executing `node -v` command from command prompt. You should be able to see the nodejs version. Once this command execution is successful, you shoule ba able to add android platform.

Comment: I've added nodejs installation folder in my Path variable: C:\Program Files\nodejs. I can succesfully execute node -v (it responds with v4.4.0), but the error with cordova is still there

Comment: @AlexandruPufan Did you tried executing platform add command from new command prompt window?

Comment: I think so, which exact command? I've executed npm version, it gives me this info: { todo: '1.1.1',
  npm: '2.14.20',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  http_parser: '2.5.2',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '46',
  node: '4.4.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2g',
  uv: '1.8.0',
  v8: '4.5.103.35',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }

Comment: @AlexandruPufan Also the reason i posted the answer confidently is because nodejs path setting was missing and the error you got clearly says illegal instruction while executing "node "$basedir/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova" "$@""

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114127/discussion-between-gandhi-and-alexandru-pufan).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it, after upgrading my Windows to Service Pack 1, the error is gone